# Drush is unable to update my site

Tags: drush, updating

I'm trying to update my drupal core though drush. But how hard i trie, it won't work. I''m using drush pm-update but it fails. Below the output of the drush debug.

Tnx in advance

```
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.05 sec, 4.34 MB]                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.28 root directory at /var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web [0.06 sec, 5.95 MB]                                                                [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.07 sec, 5.96 MB]                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.12 sec, 6.47 MB]                                                                                            [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.13 sec, 6.7 MB]                                                                           [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.15 sec, 6.72 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.15 sec, 6.72 MB]                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.16 sec, 7.55 MB]                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_login() [1.12 sec, 41.71 MB]                                                                                 [bootstrap]
Found command: pm-update (commandfile=pm) [1.21 sec, 42.14 MB]                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/pm/updatecode.pm.inc [1.21 sec, 42.17 MB]                                                                                [bootstrap]
Refreshing update status information ...
Done.
Update information last refreshed: ma, 07/28/2014 - 21:53

Update status information on all installed and enabled Drupal projects:
 Naam                       Geïnstalleerde versie  Proposed version  Status
 Alchemy                    7.x-1.0-beta1          7.x-1.0-beta1     Actueel
 Drupal core                7.28                   7.30              SECURITY UPDATE available
 Content Analysis           7.x-1.0-beta6          7.x-1.0-beta6     Actueel
 Context                    7.x-3.2                7.x-3.2           Actueel
 Chaos tool suite (ctools)  7.x-1.4                7.x-1.4           Actueel
 Keyword Research           7.x-1.0-alpha4         7.x-1.0-alpha4    Actueel
 Localization update        7.x-1.0                7.x-1.0           Actueel
 Metatag                    7.x-1.0-beta9          7.x-1.0-rc1       Nieuwe versie beschikbaar
 Nice Menus                 7.x-2.5                7.x-2.5           Actueel
 Piwik Web Analytics        7.x-2.5                7.x-2.5           Actueel
 Site map                   7.x-1.2                7.x-1.2           Actueel
 Site verification          7.x-1.1                7.x-1.1           Actueel
 Superfish                  7.x-1.9                7.x-1.9           Actueel
 Token                      7.x-1.5                7.x-1.5           Actueel
 Webform                    7.x-3.20               7.x-3.20          Actueel
 Wysiwyg                    7.x-2.2                7.x-2.2           Actueel
 XML sitemap                7.x-2.0                7.x-2.0           Actueel
 Busy                       7.x-1.5                7.x-1.5           Actueel


NOTE: A code update for the Drupal core is available.
Drupal core will be updated after all of the non-core modules are updated.

Code updates will be made to the following projects:
WD php: Notice: Undefined variable: print in pm_update_packages() (line 237 of /usr/share/drush/commands/pm/updatecode.pm.inc). [1.27 sec, 43.04 MB]            [notice]
Metatag [metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1]

Note: Updated projects can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.
Note: A backup of your package will be stored to backups directory if it is not managed by a supported version control system.
Note: If you have made any modifications to any file that belongs to one of these projects, you will have to migrate those modifications after updating.
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Starting to update Metatag code at sites/all/modules/metatag... [13.69 sec, 43.02 MB]                                                                           [notice]
Executing: svn info '/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/sites/all/modules/metatag' [13.69 sec, 43.03 MB]                                                        [notice]
  svn: '/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/sites/all/modules/metatag' is not a working copy
Calling mkdir(/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/backup, 511)
Calling mkdir(/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/backup/modules, 511)
Calling mkdir(/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/backup/modules/20140729205514, 511)
Calling rename(/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/sites/all/modules/metatag, /var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/backup/modules/20140729205514/metatag)
Downloading project metatag ... [13.92 sec, 43.05 MB]                                                                                                           [notice]
Executing: wget -P . http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar.gz [13.92 sec, 43.06 MB]                                                      [notice]
  --2014-07-29 20:55:28--  http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar.gz
  Resolving ftp.drupal.org... 140.211.166.134
  Connecting to ftp.drupal.org|140.211.166.134|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
  Length: 87802 (86K) [application/x-gzip]
  Saving to: “./metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar.gz”

       0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 58%  104K 0s
      50K .......... .......... .......... .....                100%  221K=0.6s

  2014-07-29 20:55:29 (133 KB/s) - “./metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar.gz” saved [87802/87802]

Downloading metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar.gz was successful. [14.92 sec, 43.06 MB]                                                                                    [notice]
Md5 checksum of metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar.gz verified. [14.92 sec, 43.06 MB]                                                                                      [notice]
Executing: gzip -d metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar.gz [14.92 sec, 43.06 MB]                                                                                             [notice]
Executing: tar -xf metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar [14.95 sec, 43.06 MB]                                                                                                [notice]
Calling unlink(metatag-7.x-1.0-rc1.tar)
Project metatag was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.x-1.0-rc1.
Backups were saved into the directory /var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/backup/modules/20140729205514/metatag. [15.02 sec, 43.06 MB]                        [ok]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/core/clear.cache.inc [15.02 sec, 43.06 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/core/clear.cache.inc [15.02 sec, 43.08 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/core/clear.cache.inc [15.02 sec, 43.09 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/core/clear.cache.inc [15.02 sec, 43.09 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/core/clear.cache.inc [15.02 sec, 43.09 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/core/clear.cache.inc [15.02 sec, 43.09 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/core/clear.cache.inc [15.02 sec, 43.09 MB]                                                                               [bootstrap]
Calling call_user_func(drupal_flush_all_caches)
'all' cache was cleared [16.99 sec, 49.06 MB]                                                                                                                [success]
Undefined variable: print in pm_update_packages() (regel 237 van /usr/share/drush/commands/pm/updatecode.pm.inc). [16.99 sec, 49.06 MB]                         [notice]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/pm/updatecode.pm.inc [17 sec, 48.88 MB]                                                                                  [bootstrap]
Refreshing update status information ...
Done.
Update information last refreshed: ma, 07/28/2014 - 21:53

Update status information on all installed and enabled Drupal projects:
 Naam                       Geïnstalleerde versie  Proposed version  Status
 Alchemy                    7.x-1.0-beta1          7.x-1.0-beta1     Actueel
 Drupal core                7.28                   7.30              SECURITY UPDATE available
 Content Analysis           7.x-1.0-beta6          7.x-1.0-beta6     Actueel
 Context                    7.x-3.2                7.x-3.2           Actueel
 Chaos tool suite (ctools)  7.x-1.4                7.x-1.4           Actueel
 Keyword Research           7.x-1.0-alpha4         7.x-1.0-alpha4    Actueel
 Localization update        7.x-1.0                7.x-1.0           Actueel
 Metatag                    7.x-1.0-beta9          7.x-1.0-rc1       Nieuwe versie beschikbaar
 Nice Menus                 7.x-2.5                7.x-2.5           Actueel
 Piwik Web Analytics        7.x-2.5                7.x-2.5           Actueel
 Site map                   7.x-1.2                7.x-1.2           Actueel
 Site verification          7.x-1.1                7.x-1.1           Actueel
 Superfish                  7.x-1.9                7.x-1.9           Actueel
 Token                      7.x-1.5                7.x-1.5           Actueel
 Webform                    7.x-3.20               7.x-3.20          Actueel
 Wysiwyg                    7.x-2.2                7.x-2.2           Actueel
 XML sitemap                7.x-2.0                7.x-2.0           Actueel
 Busy                       7.x-1.5                7.x-1.5           Actueel


Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Executing: svn info '/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/drupal-7.30' [30.11 sec, 49.21 MB]                                                                      [notice]
  svn: '/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/drupal-7.30' is not a working copy
Calling mkdir(/var/www/my-site.nl-dev/web/backup, 511)
Drush command could not be completed. [30.16 sec, 49.25 MB]
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show the command line that you're running, but it looks like you're using the various --svn* options to pm-update.  I don't think these are working well right now; try to do the update without them, and do your version control operations by hand after the update completes.

Comment: Just for more clarity... Drush 7 and later are not compatible with directories that are controlled by SVN.